# Slicing in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I've a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`.

In my django templates, I want the output as

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

This is what I'm doing:-

```
{% for i in list|slice:"::2" %}
    {{i}} {{}} // how do I get the second element?
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing?

Following is the python equivalent:-

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
    print list[i], list[i+1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea what you mean by the "second element". Slicing a list like that will give you `['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']`, and `i` will be each one in turn.

I suspect you don't want to do this at all; you probably want to loop through the entire list and use `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}` to determine when to insert a new paragraph or break tag.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Kindly have a look at updated question (The python equivalent).

Comment: That's not equivalent at all. The "Python equivalent" would be `for i in lst[::2]`.

Comment: My Mistake. Yes, `for i in lst[::2]` would be more apt. How can I print `i`th and `i+1`th index in django template.

Comment: You can't, because `i` is not an index, it is the element itself. My thoughts on how to solve the problem are already given above.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer. You can also use [cycle tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) for that.

```
{% for el in my_list %}
    {{ el }}
    {% cycle ' ' '<br>' %}
{% endfor %}
```

will give you desired output:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```